# how to mock database layer in golang using testify/mock

Tags: go, server, mocking, testify

I am trying to run unit test on a server, and using "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock" for mocking database layer. Putting all the code here will make it very messy so i created a small project which will give the idea of my code structure and what i am really trying to achieve "https://github.com/utkarsh17ife/goMockPractice". 
You can pull this code and run "go test ./..."
(Not sure giving the github link is the correct thing to do here, but i feel it will make things easier)

Server struct has a field db which is of type interface, so when we create a normal server the db is assigned with the real database, but while testing it is assigned with the mock database. But the problem is i cannot do the below on the db

```
srv.db.On("Insert", "some data").Return(true)
srv.db.AssertExpectations(t)
```

As the db interface does not have "On" and "AssertExpectations" field.

Looks like this is not the way to implement mocking, please let me know correct way of testing this.

Comment: You might consider using a library already built for mocking databases, such as [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock).

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever functions you want to your mock struct. The only limitation is that it has to implement at least the `DbStore` interface. Any additional functions are fine to add if you need them for your tests.

Comment: Yup, i understand that, but "On" and "AssertExpectations" are already present in mock package i need to use those instead of adding my own functions, that is the reason i feel the test structure that i have setup is wrong, but not sure what is the correct way